# Load ProfileBase without HTTP Context

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm in the process of converting user profile data that was serialized in the classic ASP.Net Membership Provider for use in SimpleMembership.  I cannot figure out how to get the `ProfileBase` object for every user in the system.

If a *specific* user is logged in, I can do something like:

```
MyModel myModel = 
    (MyModel)HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("MyKey");
```

where *MyKey* refers to a profile key established in `web.config` like this:

```
<add name="MyModel" type="MyNS.MyModel" serializeAs="Binary" />
```

However, without the benefit of an HTTP context (I'm trying to do this for all users in the system, not a logged-in user) I can't figure out how to load the profile and ultimately an instance of `MyModel` for each user in the system.

I have tried:

```
ProfileInfoCollection profiles = 
     ProfileManager.GetAllProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption.All);

foreach (var profile in profiles)
{
    var pi = (ProfileBase)profile;
    // OOPS!  Unfortunately GetAllProfiles returns 
    // ProfileInfo and not ProfileCommon or ProfileBase
}
```

and

```
MembershipUserCollection existingUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers();
foreach (MembershipUser mu in existingUsers)
{
    mu. // OOPS! No link to the profile from the user...
}
```

How can I retrieve the `ProfileCommon` or `ProfileBase` instance for each profile in the system, and thus ultimately the `MyModel` associated with each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not find an answer to this question, I opted to just read the profile data directly from SQL.

It turns out that the format is straightforward.  In aspnet_Profile:

- PropertyNames uses a format NameOfProperty:TypeFlag:Offset:Length (repeat for all properties).
- FlagType is "S" for string or "B" for binary
- Offset is the offset in the appropriate data field
- Length is the length of data in the appropriate data field
- PropertyValuesString holds all string properties concatenated without a delimiter.
- PropertyValuesBinary holds all binary properties concatenated without a delimiter.
- BinaryFormatter is used to serialize binary (non-string) properties

Here's a little code I wrote to parse the data:

```
private class Migrate_PropNames
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsString { get; set; }
    public int Offset { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
}
....

Dictionary<string, Migrate_PropNames> propInfo = ParsePropInfo(propertyNames);
// Example string property
string firstName = Migrate_GetString(propInfo["FirstName"], propertyValuesString);
// Example binary property
MyType myType = 
    Migrate_GetBinary<MyType>(propInfo["MyTypeKey"], propertyValuesBinary));


private T Migrate_GetBinary<T>(Migrate_PropNames propNames, byte[] propertyValuesBinary)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[propNames.Length];
    Array.Copy(propertyValuesBinary, propNames.Offset, data, 0, propNames.Length);

    var fmt = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        T original = (T)fmt.Deserialize(ms);
        return original;
    }
}

private string Migrate_GetString(Migrate_PropNames propNames, string propertyNames)
{
    return propertyNames.Substring(propNames.Offset, propNames.Length);
}

private Dictionary<string, Migrate_PropNames> ParsePropInfo(string propertyNames)
{
    Dictionary<string, Migrate_PropNames> result = new Dictionary<string,Migrate_PropNames>();

    string[] parts = propertyNames.Split(new string[] { ":"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i += 4)
    {
        Migrate_PropNames pn = new Migrate_PropNames();
        pn.Name = parts[i];
        pn.IsString = (parts[i + 1] == "S");
        pn.Offset = int.Parse(parts[i + 2]);
        pn.Length = int.Parse(parts[i + 3]);

        result.Add(pn.Name, pn);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I hope this helps someone.  I'll gladly accept a different answer that correctly shows how to use the API.

Answer (score 0):

From the `ProfileInfo` or `MemberShipUser` object, you should can get a `ProfileBase` one using `ProfileBase.Create(string username)`.